# How to store code in a javascript variable for prism

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb

I'm trying to display some code on my website. I'm using prism which is working well, however, I'm eventually going to have to store the code I'm trying to present in a mongodb database. Right now I'm having trouble figuring out how to save the code as variable `codeSnippet` and presenting it. How do I do this?

**What it is suppose to look like**

```
class DispalyCodeExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <pre>
        <code className="language-javascript">
          {`
let animals = {
  cow: 'moo',
  mouse: 'squeak'
}
let mouse = 'cow';
let x = animals[mouse];
          `}
        </code>
      </pre>
    );
  }
}
```

**My attempt that's not working - due to my codeSnippet variable**

```
class DispalyCodeExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  }

  render() {
    const codeSnippet =  {
    let animals = {
      cow: 'moo',
      mouse: 'squeak'
    }
    let mouse = 'cow';
    let x = animals[mouse];
              };
    return (
      <pre>
        <code className="language-javascript">
         {codeSnippet}
        </code>
      </pre>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would `base64` encode the entire class, then store it in **MongoDB**. When you're ready to display on a web page, `base64` decode the block of your source code. This way, all source code won't be changed to **HTML characters**. All variables and functions will be preserved.

Comment: That seems to be a great solution, however, when used with prismjs the styling isn't being applied. It doesn't seem to recognise the opening {` and closing `} brackets. Any suggestions.

Comment: all good figured out I can't save those brackets into my base64 code. Thanks again.